# How to determine that synthesis is done in Quartus?

Tags: verilog, quartus

My design is done in Verilog and I need to select specific solution for synthesis in *Altera Quartus II*. I know that many tools have predefined macros, for example *Icarus Verilog* has built-in macro `__ICARUS__`. But I was unable to find such macro for Quartus. Is it a simple way to detect it?

Comment: Im not sure if Quartus does predefine any macros, but you can always define your own in the quartus project (`Assignments->Settings->Compilater Settings->Verilog HDL Input->Verilog HDL macro`)

Comment: @Unn, is this applicable to just one project or is it that once macro is created, it is applicable to all projects?

Comment: Should only apply to the current project, but I haven't tried it extensively to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Altera/Intel Quartus II Integrated Synthesis (QIS) has predefined macro that is used extensively by QIS in their demos and IPs. This macro is actually undocumented but it works in all known versions of Quartus II. Here is it:

```
`ifdef ALTERA_RESERVED_QIS
  // The code that is used for Quartus Synthesis
`else
  // The code that is used for other software
`endif
```